# jQuery UI Tooltip appears outside the window so viewers can't see it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

On [jQuery's webste](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content) this problem is happening. When you hover over the image the Tooltip appears below the image, thereby the user can't see the Tooltip.

There is room to show the tip on the top of the image, so the user can see it.

Is there a way to fix this problem? I have seen other Tooltips that show on the top or the bottom depending on where it will show up best.

Can jQuery Tooltip do this?

Comment: set collison property of position ....see docs.

Comment: @charlietfl It looks like the question is asking about the borders only of the visible pane (as opposed to the full scrollable pane) which `collision` doesn't care about. OP, could you clarify? It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: Correct, the tooltip should show up within visible pane. collision seems to ignore the visible pane. According to the documentation, it defaults to flipfit, yet it chooses to show the tooltip outside the visible pane, when there is plenty of room to show it in the visible pane.

Comment: @blgt not sure why you say collision doesn't care about window, that's exactly what it does do as stated in docs

Comment: @charlietfl The *window* pane that `collision` deals with is the entire scrollable area, which may be bigger than the area actually visible in a smaller browser. OP wants to avoid the need to scroll to see the tooltip. I don't think this is supported out-of-the-box

Comment: @bglt no it is not. The docs clearly state `overflow of the window`

Comment: @charlietfl You're reading it wrong: [`When the positioned element overflows the window in some direction, move it to an alternative position.`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) When the window has enough content to have a scrollbar without the tooltip, this condition will **not** trigger and the tooltip will **not** be repositioned (as it won't "overflow" by itself). Give it a try

Comment: Is there a way to notify jQuery of this issue? Showing a tooltip outside the visible window is not a good user experience.

Comment: Is there a way to have the tooltip always appear in the upper right corner of the visible window so it can always be seen?

Comment: @OahuRE Actually it's roughly what you'd expect. If you're that concerned about it, why not just make it follow the mouse ([`track:true`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-track))?

Comment: @blgt I don't agree that this is what you would expect. I would expect a tooltip to appear inside the visible pane when there is room for it, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around I decided to always have it appear in the top right corner.

The code below works, including allowing HTML in the tool tip. Note that I need the 640px div otherwise the 640px image will appear outside the visible area the first time it comes up.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jquery tooltip</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type='text/css'>
div.ui-tooltip {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.ui-tooltip {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    line-height: 150%;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function () {
      $(".RightTooltip").tooltip({
          content: function () {
              return $(this).prop('title')
      },
      position: {
          my: "right top",
          at: "right top",
          of: window
          }
      });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="Text"><a class="RightTooltip" href="#" title='<div style="width:640px;">Image below.</div><img src="http://www.oahure.com/data/2014/201417772/2.jpg"/>'>Tooltip</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```